I need the right syntax to add parameter strings to the URL of a JSON request
I need to create, programatically, the complete URL with parameters that will play a JSON request in a time API to get a certain results... as if this URL had been typed in the browser navigation bar...
The API documentation is very good, it shows me all the parameters and when I program in its interface the string I wish and execute, it works very well and gives me the desired results.
However, i don't dominate how should I compose manually the URL syntax to reflect the same parameters on a line typed in the browser address bar... I've tried countless sintaxis and none works. The Request URL displayed by the interface corresponds to the basic get, without the paramters I need to insert... and although I knew that the information I need is explicit at the API interface, I don't know how to put it in the right syntax.
Could anyone tell me how I should format this URL to be typed in the browser without using the API documentation interface?
API Documentation
That's all. I need the right syntax.
Edit:
Luuk » Thank you for your answer and sorry for putting an image and not the documentation link. I don't know how to use this forum very well yet. The indicated literature is quite old. Such a post is almost 14 years old. After some broken links, several redirections and plenty of Google search, I conclude that I should use 'curl' with commands in 'terminal'. For this I am using Powershell.
Although familiar with JSON requests generated from Excel VBA, the process of conversion, adaptation and adequacy to reproduce the same requests on Windows PowerShell is tortuous! I've been trying dozens of possible combinations and I can't get to the right syntax »
curl -x https://timeapi.io/api/calculation/current/increment -d "timeZone": "Europe/Amsterdam", "timeSpan": "16:03:45:17"
curl https://timeapi.io/api/calculation/custom/increment -d {"timeZone": "Europe/Amsterdam","dateTime": "2024-11-27 05:45:00","timeSpan": "16:03:45:17","dstAmbiguity": ""}
curl https://timeapi.io/api/calculation/custom/increment -d {"timeZone": "Europe/Madrid","dateTime": "2024-10-27 01:00:00","timeSpan": "00:01:00:00","dstAmbiguity": ""}
curl https://timeapi.io/api/calculation/custom/increment -d "timeZone"="Europe/Madrid","dateTime"="2024-10-27 01:00:00","timeSpan"="00:01:00:00","dstAmbiguity"=""
curl https://timeapi.io/api/calculation/custom/increment -d timeZone="Europe/Madrid",dateTime="2024-10-27 01:00:00",timeSpan="00:01:00:00",dstAmbiguity=""
curl https://timeapi.io/api/calculation/custom/increment -d "timeZone"="Europe/Madrid","dateTime"="2024-10-27 01:00:00","timeSpan"="00:01:00:00","dstAmbiguity"=""
Please, could anyone tell me what the correct syntax should be?
It's been days since I've been devoting hours to this and it is not being possible to reach the correct answer.
@>-->---

That request has a body, which you can't put into the URL. And it is a POST, whereas typing a URL in the browser address bar makes a GET.

more info: How to manually send HTTP POST requests from a browser

In PowerShell use curl.exe not just curl. And -x by itself is wrong; use -X POST (uppercase X) or leave it out entirely because -d already defaults the method to POST

In the future, please provide a link, not a screenshot, to the documentation.
https://timeapi.io/swagger/index.html
The example is written in Python.
Specify the request method (in this case post) and pass the request body in data or json.
I usually prefer json if possible.
import requests

response = requests.post(
    url='https://timeapi.io/api/calculation/custom/increment',
    json={
        "timeZone": "Europe/Amsterdam",
        "dateTime": "2024-11-27 05:45:00",
        "timeSpan": "16:03:45:17",
        "dstAmbiguity": ""
    }
)

print(response.status_code)
print(response.json())

If you use the past tense from the example in dateTime you will get an error.

requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='timeapi.io', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/calculation/custom/increment (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, '[SSL: UNEXPECTED_EOF_WHILE_READING] EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1002)')))

When you do not receive an error (because of a busy website), you will get an answer like (formatted for better readability):
{'timeZone': 'Europe/Amsterdam', 
 'originalDateTime': '2024-11-27T05:45:00', 
 'usedTimeSpan': '16:03:45:17', 
 'calculationResult': {'year': 2024, 'month': 12, 'day': 13, 
                       'hour': 9, 'minute': 30, 'seconds': 17,
                       'milliSeconds': 0, 
                       'dateTime': '2024-12-13T09:30:17', 
                       'date': '12/13/2024', 
                       'time': '09:30', 
                       'dstActive': False}
}

A curl option that can be done in the terminal.
curl -X POST "https://timeapi.io/api/calculation/custom/increment" \
   -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
   -d '{"timeZone": "Europe/Amsterdam","dateTime": "2024-11-27 05:45:00","timeSpan": "16:03:45:17","dstAmbiguity": ""}'


That curl will work in a Unix shell (including WSL) but not Windows Powershell which OP says they are using; there you need curl.exe to get the actual curl program in W10 up (and backtick to escape EOL rather than backslash) while bare curl is an alias for Invoke-WebRequest -- which does have the capability of doing HTTPS POST but only using quite different options.
